# A text box which is visible across all the worksheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have an Excel workbook with 8 worksheets. I want to create a TextBox with an arrow attached to it and place it at the bottom left Corner, right above the worksheet's names. I want this text box to visible even when i move to next worksheet. It would be used as a comment that is common to the all the worksheets.

Comment: How about creating a worksheet, place the comment in the name, and give it a color to make it distinctly visible? I know, not exactly what you're asking, but unless you want to create that textbox on every sheet, there's not really an option.

Comment: Is the text the same for all text boxes?  Where will the arrow point?  To the specic sheet tab?  Maybe to the same cell on each sheet?  to different cells on every sheet?

Comment: I can suggest you VBA code(Macro) will create Text box in all sheets at one click & then after you find it across sheets,, confirm through comments will the work for you ?

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald: The text is same across all the Sheets. Example: 3 out of 8 worksheets are base data sheet. I want to put a curly brace on all the 3 worksheets and write "Base data sheet" in the text box. When i move to any other worksheet then also this text box should Show. Just like the worksheet Tabs that are always visible irrespective of the active worksheet.

Comment: @LPChip: Yes, I can probably try doing this for all the database Sheets. Just want the TextBox to make it more clear and prompt.

Comment: @rajesh s: I think this will do, if the text box is created at the same place in all the Sheets. But majorly, I want the TextBox to be visible on the workbook, irrespective of the current worksheet.

Comment: What is the reason to change the name to a ~ with a comment? If there is a certain distinction or other reason, there are other methods. I bet there is a far better solution to what you're trying to do. For example, you can hide sheets, give them colors, make their names shorter, etc...

Comment: @Priyanka,, check my answer now I've posted the code as you demanded through comments above will help you to create Text box in all 8 Sheets at same place ☺

Answer (score 0):

*@Priyanka, I would like to suggest you VBA code(Macro), will create Tex box across Sheets(in all 8 Sheet), above the Sheet Names.*

```
Sub CreateTXTBox()
    For I = 1 To 8
        Sheets(I).Select
        ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.TextBox.1", Link:=False, _
        DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=50, Top:=270, Width:=100, Height:= _
        40).Select
    Next
End Sub
```

**N.B.**

- Insert this Code as Module with Workbook and RUN to create Text box in all 8 Sheets at same place.
- `For I = 1 to 8` is editable you can alter `8` if wants to create Text Box in more or less than `8 Sheets`.
- Text Box dimensions are also editable.